# Sending API key using java.net.URL

Tags: java, api, parsing, inputstream

I am trying to send an API key to access some data. This data needs to be returned as an input stream, so I can parse through it. I am using `java.net.URL` to access the site, but I can't find a way to send an API key with my http request.

```
URL url = new URL("My specified URL for the API");

        FeedMessage feed = FeedMessage.parseFrom(url.openStream());
        for (FeedEntity entity : feed.getEntityList()) {
            if (entity.hasTripUpdate()) {
                System.out.println(entity.getTripUpdate());
            }
        }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to send an API key in a header while accessing this URL. This is not something that is easily done using the standard library (not sure if it can be done at all). I'd recommend using a http client library, e.g. okhttp. Here's a beginner's tutorial to using it: https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-okhttp

Comment: I strongly recommend using a packaged library, such as Spring RestTemplate or Micronaut client, instead of hand-writing all the code. These will make it much easier to do things like include `Authorization` headers.

Comment: This is something that is very easy to do with the standard library, namely `HttpURLConnection.setHeader()`. There is no need whatsoever to use any third-party libraries. @SeanPatrickFloyd

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using these libraries to solve this problem:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import com.google.transit.realtime.GtfsRealtime.FeedEntity;
import com.google.transit.realtime.GtfsRealtime.FeedMessage;

import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
```

This allowed me to get the data I wanted from the API and then convert it into an input stream. The code that allowed me to do that is below.

```
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        try
        {
            URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("URL");

            URI uri = builder.build();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
            request.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "API-Key");


            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();

            FeedMessage feed = FeedMessage.parseFrom(content);
         }
```